# ARel: Add additional conditions to an outer join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel

I have the following models in my Rails application:

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :schedules
  scope :active, where(:active => true)
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shift
end
```

I wish to generate a collection of all active shifts and eager load any associated schedules that have `occurs_on` between two given dates. If a shift has no schedules between those dates, it should still be returned in the results.

Essentially, I want to generate SQL equivalent to:

```
SELECT shifts.*, schedules.*
FROM shifts
  LEFT JOIN schedules ON schedules.shift_id = shifts.id
    AND schedules.occurs_on BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '01/31/2012'
WHERE shifts.active = 't';
```

My first attempt was:

```
Shift.active.includes(:schedules).where("schedules.occurs_on BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '01/31/2012')
```

The problem is that the occurs_on filtering is done in the where clause, and not in the join. If a shift has no schedules in that period, it is not returned at all.

My second attempt was to use the `joins` method, but this does an inner join. Again, this will drop all shifts that have no schedules for that period.

I'm frustrated because I know the SQL I want AREL to generate, but I can't figure out how to express it with the API. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SQL fragment as the argument of your joins method call :

```
Shift.active.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN schedules ON schedules.occurs_on...')
```

Answer (score 7):

you could try some pretty raw AREL. Disclaimer: I didn't have actual `Schedule` and `Shift` classes so i couldn't test this properly, but i used some existing tables to troubleshoot it on my own machine.

```
on = Arel::Nodes::On.new(
  Arel::Nodes::Equality.new(Schedule.arel_table[:shift_id], Shift.arel_table[:id]).\
  and(Arel::Nodes::Between.new(
    Schedule.arel_table[:occurs_on],
    Arel::Nodes::And.new(2.days.ago, Time.now)
  ))
)
join = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(Schedule.arel_table, on)
Shift.joins(join).where(active: true).to_sql
```

Answer (score -1):

You can construct a raw sql query using Arel as follows:

```
@start_date
@end_date

@shift = Shift.arel_table
@schedule = Schedule.arel_table

@shift.join(@schedule)
        .on(@schedule[:shift_id].eq(@shift[:id])
              .and(@schedule[:occurs_on].between(@start_date..@end_date)))
      .to_sql
```